# Which PDL Canon IP2780 can support?

Tags: printers, printer-control-language

i'm a developer, i want to write driver for Canon IP2780, i had known GARO UFR. but i want to konw which PDL  Canon IP2780  can support ?

like HP printer, i can find which PDL it can support, but i fond nothing about Canon printer.

such as HP Deskjet 1000, it support PCL3 GUI.

i also ask Canon, but no answer so far.

i fond this 《[Canon Understanding PDLs](http://www.cmrepro.com/documents/CanonUnderstandingPDLs.pdf)》,but it is about  imagePROGRAF printer not PIXMA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo /usr/lib/cups/backup/usb` get device_id of the printer.

device_id will show which PDL is supported.